# Related to images woocommerce - Delete

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I would like to delete those images which are not in use on a website (wordpress + woocommerce).
I tried to delete the images which are not related to any post or product, but a lot of images are gone from products when I did that.

Is there any other way to do that?
I have over 1000 pictures on my site

Comment: you can make a script that delete images which is not attached to any post... but this is not guaranteed that you will not delete any image that is not being used. unless you're the only one using your site..

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following plugin to achieve this. Make sure you backup your site before you use this for the first time:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/dnui-delete-not-used-image-wordpress/